# Nested ng-repeat and push object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have written an API which consumes this JSON

```
{
  "savedBy": "1",
  "symptom": "new",
  "questionSet": [{
    "question": "This is question 1",
    "options": [{
        "values": "okasdsad"
      },
      {
        "values": "asdsad",
        "subQuestionSet": [{
          "question": "This is question 1",
          "options": [{
              "values": "okasdsad"
            },
            {
              "values": "oaskdosakdo"
            },
            {
              "values": "yoyoyo"
            },
            {
              "values": "nonono"
            }
          ]
        }]
      },
      {
        "values": "yoyoyo"
      },
      {
        "values": "nonono"
      }
    ]
  }]
}
```

Now I have written the front-end in angular so that I can send this JSON value by the form,

HTML.

```
<div class="question" ng-repeat="qItem in questionVo track by $index">
  {{questionVo}}
  <div class="col-md-12">QUS {{$index+1}}
    <input type="text" ng-model="qItem.question" class="form-control" id=""></div>
  {{question}}
  <div class="form-inline col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">

    <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="items in optionsVo track by $index">
      {{optionsVo}}
      <label>{{$index+1}}</label><input ng-model="items.values" type="text" class="form-control" id="">
      <i class="fa fa-plus-square" ng-click="addoptionsVo(items)"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-minus-square" ng-click="optionsVo.splice($index, 1)"></i>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="showSubset()">Add Subset</button>

      <!--------subset ----->

      <div class="question" ng-if="showSubsetView == true" ng-repeat="SubqItem in ssss track by $index">
        <div class="col-md-12">QUS {{$index+1}}
          <input type="text" ng-model="question" class="form-control" id=""></div>
        <div class="form-inline col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
          {{itemsz.ssss}}

          <div class="form-group" data-ng-repeat="Subitems in optionsVo track by $index">
            <label>{{$index+1}}</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="">
            <i class="fa fa-plus-square" ng-click="addoptionsVo($index)"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-minus-square" ng-click="optionsVo.splice($index, 1)"></i>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Add Subset</button>

          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>

          <div class="btn-margin"><button class="btn btn-primary">Add More</button></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>

      <!--------subset ----->

    </div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <div class="btn-margin"><button class="btn btn-primary">Add More</button></div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

**Angular JS**

```
$scope.questionVo = [{
  question: '',
}];

$scope.addquestionVo = function($event) {
  $scope.questionVo.push({
    question: '',
  });
};

$scope.optionsVo = [{}];

$scope.addoptionsVo = function($event) {
  $scope.optionsVo.push({});
};
```

**PROBLEM**
1.)when i add second question in the array the **options** remain same like in the 1st question
2.) i want to make json same as the api json in the question through angular

also

```
"options": [{
    "values": "okasdsad"
  },
  "subQuestionSet": [{
    "question": "This is question 1",
    "options": [{
        "values": "okasdsad"
      },
      {
        "values": "oaskdosakdo"
      },
      {
        "values": "yoyoyo"
      },
      {
        "values": "nonono"
      }
    ]
  }] {
    "values": "okasdsad"
  }
]
```

can anyone help me with this?
anyone>?

**PLUNKER** https://plnkr.co/edit/33mVEQ?p=preview

EDIT : i found strange issue with plunker / in chrome it is giving `{[ "values": "asdsa"]]` but in plunker it is becoming `[{ "values": "asdsa" }]`

Comment: put it in some fiddle

Comment: ok..............

Comment: try this https://plnkr.co

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/0JndKowvN3J5CyXo8mJC?p=preview @svarog

Comment: @StarkButtowski updated in plunker

Comment: @doe it is not working. Check again

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/33mVEQ?p=preview try this @StarkButtowski

Comment: @doe what you want to achieve.Clear i asking the question."Need to add questions to that array or edit the existing one"?

Comment: 1.)when i add second question in the array the options remain same like in the 1st question 2.) i want to make json same as the api json in the question through angular @StarkButtowski

Comment: see the plunker try adding multiple quesiton  with multiple option you will get the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the below approach that matches your requirement. The `options` should be inside the `question` array.

```js
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('medparser',[]);



app.controller('addquestionController', function($scope, $http, $window, $rootScope, $timeout) {



  $scope.addoptionsVo = function(no) {

    $scope.questionVo[no].options.push({
      values: ''
    });
  };

  $scope.questionVo = [{
    question: '',
    options: [{
      "values": ""
    }]
  }];

  $scope.addquestionVo = function($event) {
    console.log("ASDSA");
    $scope.questionVo.push({
      question: '',
      options: [{
        "values": ""
      }]
    });
  };
  //////////////////////////////////////////////
  $scope.showSubsetView = false;
  $scope.showSubset = function() {
    $scope.showSubsetView = true;
  };






});

////////////////////////////////////////
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="medparser" ng-controller="addquestionController">
  <div class="intro-header">
    <div style="height:1px"></div>
    <nav class="navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index1.html">
            <div class="logo">
              <img src="images/logo.png"></div>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="header-text">
          Questionnaire For Doctors
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="container header-padding">
    <div class="col-md-6">Symptoms</div><br>
    <div class="col-md-6"><input type="text" ng-model="keyword" class="form-control" ng-keyup="searchsymptoms(keyword)" typeahead="state.name for state in symptomsList | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" id=""></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    question : {{questionVo}}
    <div class="question" ng-repeat="qItem in questionVo track by $index">

      <div class="col-md-12">QUS {{$index+1}}
        <input type="text" ng-model="qItem.question" class="form-control" id=""></div>
      {{question}}
      <div class="form-inline col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">


        <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="items in qItem.options track by $index">

          <label>{{$index+1}}</label><input ng-model="items.values" type="text" class="form-control" id="">
          <i class="fa fa-plus-square" ng-click="addoptionsVo(items)"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-minus-square" ng-click="optionsVo.splice($index, 1)"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <div class="btn-margin"><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addoptionsVo($index)">Add Option</button></div>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pull-left header-padding"><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addquestionVo($event)">Add Question</button></div>
    <div class="pull-right header-padding"><button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button></div>
  </div>
</body>
```